# Displacement modifier doing weird things to different meshed

Tags: uv, displacement

I am using blender 2.92 and it does not seem to let me control displacement on my mesh. Let me explain, let's take cube for reference

1. I subdivide one of it's sides and create a group from the vertices of that side
2. I apply a displacement modifier and insert image I want to do displacement with in the properties panel
3. In the modifier panel I set the coordinates to UV and set the vertex group to the one I chose in step 1
4. split the screen and turn 2nd screen to UV viewer where I adjust the pattern. As you can see this is what it looks like in image 1.

First image is how I edit the pattern and second is where I see the outcome.[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

Now here is my issue, I do the same stuff for a more detailed mesh but I use remesh modifier and this is what I get

[image: Third image]

There is no frame of the mesh in UV viewer as opposed to the first image. The mesh is a fair bit more detailed and I am not sure how to get the UV view to show me the deconstructed mesh. The method does work for the mesh though as you can see in image four.

[image: Image four]

When I try using remesh for my cube instead of subdividing the side I get the same results as with the heart mesh, I suppose using remesh modifier could have something to do with this. [image: Mesh of the heart before remesh modifier].

The 5th image is showing the mesh before remesh modifier is used. I am trying to create a 3D texture which will be felt when the piece is 3D printed. Sorry for the long explanation, hope you guys know how I can get the mesh to show up in the UV side of the screen.

I have added this image for Nathan about UV projections.
[image]

Comment: You're not showing any UV mapping on your heart.  Does it have a UV map?  Is it a meaningful UV map?

Comment: @Nathan I have updated the post and mentioned about remesh modifier. Yes the heart does have a mesh before I use remesh modifier. This seems to be an issue with a remesh modifier I think.

Comment: I don't think you know what a UV map is, which suggests that's what your problem is.  Select all verts of your heart in edit, u-> project from view, take a look; change perspective and repeat.  You're using a UV mapped texture, so you need to specify how it maps by creating/editing the UV.

Comment: Please use paragraphs and proper spacing in your posts so they are easier to read

Comment: @Nathan thanks. I did what you said and it started appearing but the selected vertices I have projected turn out to be in a slanted configuration. See the image I posted

Comment: @user121012 Yes, there are a few billion different ways to map your UV; I wanted you to start to see what UV was.  You need to learn how to map UV by either watching some tutorials or playing or, preferably, both.

Comment: @Nathan The mapping did not change the way the displacement looks as can be seen in image 4. I will definitely watch tutorial videos, 100%. So, you think this is a UV mapping issue? If I figure out that it should solve the issue?

Comment: @user121012 Yes, it is due to UV, and you need to learn how UV works.